# What steps should I take next to improve my accuracy? Can data be the problem?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I built various ML models using sklearn for a binary classification problem. The data-set is provided to me by my professor for this comparative study.

[image: my results are here]
  [my jupyter notebook and dataset can be found here](https://github.com/rohan260696/ML-Assignment.git)

As I am getting very low accuracy, I fear that I must be doing something wrong while building the model. So I tested my decision tree on the inbuilt data-set in sklearn (breast cancer data-set) which is very similar to my data-set as both are binary classifications. Here I get an mean accuracy of 95 %. So I think right now that the problem might be my data-set. Can I get some help on how do I pre-process my data or any other steps that I might look into to improve accuracy.

Comment: Don't attach images in questions, add your code/results and use the code syntax highlight button to highlight them.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Encode labels**

Categorical data are variables that contain label values rather than numeric values.The number of possible values is often limited to a fixed set.
For example, users are typically described by country, gender, age group etc. We will use Label Encoder to label the categorical data. Label Encoder is the part of SciKit Learn library in Python and used to convert categorical data, or text data, into numbers, which our predictive models can better understand.

```
#Encoding categorical data values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y)
```

2. **Feature scaling**

Most of the times, your dataset will contain features highly varying in magnitudes, units and range. But since, most of the machine learning algorithms use Eucledian distance between two data points in their computations. We need to bring all features to the same level of magnitudes. This can be achieved by scaling. This means that you’re transforming your data so that it fits within a specific scale, like 0–100 or 0–1. We will use StandardScaler method from SciKit-Learn library.

```
#Feature Scalingfrom sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

3. **Choosing Right model**

You kight also want to vhoose the appropriate model. You can't just use neural nets or so for all problems it's the no free luch theorem. For this you could use K-fold cross validation, AIC and BIC

Comment: I dont have categorical data, I have normalised my data between 0 and 1, and I am using stratified K fold with gridsearch.

Comment: It would be best now if you could use the Binary cross entropy approach that should give a higher accuracy

Comment: I have also a written a research paper on the Breast cancer dataset so I can help you with neural networks which I finally used but I also experimented with BCE, which gave me pretty good acc too